Concatenate tappable and non-tappable SwiftUI Text
There are a couple of similar questions.
I am trying to add a tap gesture to a subset of a text:
HStack(spacing: 0) {
  Text("aaaaa ") +
  Text("bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb ") +
  Text("...")
    .onTapGesture { print("set some state var to true so that a model is shown")}
    .foregroundColor(.blue) +
  Text(" ccc ccc ")
}

This fails with The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions. It is not clear to me what the actual issue is beyond that .onTapGesture is causing the error.
I have tried a couple of things without concatenation (+) using Button but nothing achieves the continuous text that I am looking for. Is there another way of accomplishing this? I am wanting to set a state variable so that a model is shown when a tap gesture is recognized on a text.
I also have cases where more than one tap is to be recognized on a long sentence (i.e. "Customer, tap [this] to see your choices or tap [here] to see other choices") which means applying the tap gesture to an entire HStack should not work as intended.
